# Handling Large Amounts Of Folders In Linux, Best Structure For Efficiency

Tags: linux, filesystems, php

I am creating a new PHP application for my client, and need some advice on the File structure and possible pitfalls. Their current system is not compliant with federal law, as it contains identifiable information about users.

Currently, there are folders that contain PDF's that are generated for every user, and the existing website is being served from a Windows machine, which makes the old developer's structure make sense to me. It's designed as follows.

```
Files > A > B > Alan_Bob_1234
```

My idea is to create new folders for every user using a Unique ID. But storing all of them within the same folder.

**My question:**

How detrimental to processing speed would having all 14,000+ folders and growing be when I want to call a known file location. For example, I want to call:

```
Files > 0cowxuRoGj > abc.pdf
```

Will having so many folders in the main Files folder cause issues for speed when calling a known file location?

Thank you.

Comment: Will the files continue to be served from a remote machine? Over Samba or NFS or something else? Will you ever need to enumerate the folders or their contents, or is it guaranteed that the full path will be known without having to do so?

Comment: If your Unique ID is sufficiently varied, you can still do a hierarchy `Files > 0 > c > 0cowxuRoGj `. If it isnt, you could hash the id into somthing small and use that as another hierarchic indexing id.

Comment: @muru, it would be assumed that the file locations will be known unless for some reason something goes wrong (which can happen). Although the folder the pdfs are contained in will always be known because it's the user's ID directly. Files are stored on the same machine that is serving the website (Dedicated server)

Comment: @meuh, That is a reasonable idea. I like it. However, I would like to completely avoid the need for subfolders if the impact is nominal. I just don't understand how the Linux file system seeks files, and what the impact of known names has in such a large subset.

Comment: The ext4 directory *htree* structure is described [here](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Hash_Tree_Directories) and is very efficient. Eg this [answer](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Hash_Tree_Directories) says 1million files in one directory on ext4 seemed to provide no overhead to their web server.

Comment: @meuh this is exactly what I was looking for but wasn't sure where to look. I think your second link was broken and I would love to read over what you found if you don't mind linking it again. Thanks!

Comment: Oops. [1 million](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19893521/5008284) link. Look at some of the other answers there, but bear in mind they are very old, and may refer to ext3 before it got the directory lookup optimisation that ext4 has. Of course, having many files in a directory can "annoy" commands like `ls` and so on, as there is so much info to read, but for direct access it is not a problem.

Comment: The "annoyance" for tools such as `ls` is a good reason to consider a hierarchical solution. Have you ever tried to debug an application that has 10,000+ files in a single directory? Ugh. (And you're considering 100x that number.)